# TCP Socket connection- Unable to read data sent from external client even after serializing through ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer

Tags: sockets, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I have implemented TCP socket server which accepts incoming XML messages from client. I could send messages through telnet.

But when I am trying to establish connection and send message through python script, I was getting IOException:CRLF not found before max message length: 2048.So I have added ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer to serialize and deserialize, but now I am getting below error.

IOException:Message length 1014132591 exceeds max message length: 2048

Though I am increasing the max message length I am getting IOException:Stream closed after 46 of 1014132591

Could someone let me know how to fix the issue.

```html
final AbstractServerConnectionFactory crLfServer = context.getBean(AbstractServerConnectionFactory.class);
 ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer serializer = new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer();
    serializer.setMaxMessageSize(1000 * 1024);
    crLfServer.setSerializer(serializer);
    crLfServer.setDeserializer(serializer);
```

I have implemented using Spring Integration.Below is the snippet for my inbound adapter

```html
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    System.out.println("Creating inbound adapter");
    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inbound = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();

    inbound.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    //inbound.
    inbound.setOutputChannel(fromTcp());
  

    return inbound;
}
```

Comment: You can't use a serializer at the server that the client doesn't understand, and you can't use a deserializer at the server that relies on a format that the client isn't sending. Raise your maximum read-line buffer, or use a technology that doesn't have such a low limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think might be better to send exactly that CRLF in your script after the message. That will be exactly delimiter for the messages to deserialize. This is one what is used by the mentioned Telnet. However you need to come back to the default deserializer in the connection factory configuration.

Comment: But my requirement has a client which uses python script to establish socket connection, send xml messages, receive acknowledgment and then closes the socket connection.The code is working fine for telnet, but its not my requirement

Comment: TCP is a stream; you need some mechanism to know when a message is "complete". Telnet uses CRLF to terminate the message. Read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-connection-factories). Your client and server have to agree what constitutes a "message" in the stream. The length header serializer expects a binary header containing the message length.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation, I understand the point you have mentioned. But I tried writing socket server in python and it talks to the client even without CRLF.

Comment: Is there a way in spring integration to implement server which accept raw socket connection rather than tcp or udp?

Comment: Spring Integration deals with messages, not streams; of course you can write custom code to read from a socket but you still need to know when the data is "complete" because the network can packetize it; how do you know you have the whole message in Python? If it's based on the data, you need a custom deserializer. Your last question is not clear. What kind of "raw socket" do you mean?

Comment: Your last question deserves a separate SO thread. However I'm not sure that there is some other low-level network protocols...

Comment: Say if the client appends CRLF, then how can we increase the maximum message size at the server end.I tried setMaxMessageSize() for ByteArrayCrLfSerializer(assuming this is the default serailizer) but still it says "IOException:CRLF not found before max message length: 2048"

Comment: Well, it has a `setMaxMessageSize()` option to configure.

Comment: Yeah it worked.But I am not sure if the external client could append CRLF.Anyways thanks for the help!!

Comment: Well, you can agree with the client what kind of delimiter they are ready to send after each message. There plenty out-of-the-box `AbstractByteArraySerializer` implementations

Comment: ok will refer to other serializer implementations based on the delimiter.Thanks!